# Selenium headless does not run on CentOS 7 with Perl, "no display specified"

Tags: perl, selenium, centos, headless

I try to run headless Selenium on CentOS7:

```
# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.2 (Maipo)"
```

I installed Xvfb and run it as

```
# /usr/bin/Xvfb :99
```

I installed firefox:

```
# firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 38.5.0
```

and run it to check if it can be run at all:

```
# export DISPLAY=:99
# firefox
```

This is the output:

```
# firefox
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99".
console.error: 
  [CustomizableUI]
  Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node
console.error: 
  [CustomizableUI]
  Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
```

Firefox seems to be running after that command:

```
# ps aux | grep firefox
root     29476  7.3 14.9 852356 152256 pts/3   Sl+  10:30   0:03 /usr/lib64/firefox/firefox
```

**EDIT**
Yes, it's running. Taking screenshot from the Xvfb by

```
DISPLAY=:99 import -window root -crop 1264x948+0+0  /tmp/screenshot.jpg
```

I can see
[image]

Now the problematic part.

I installed Selenium Remote Driver for perl

```
# cpanm Selenium::Remote::Driver
```

Then I ran standalone selenium driver:

```
# java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.49.0.jar
```

Now I run test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(browser_name=>'firefox');
$driver->get('http://www.google.com');
print $driver->get_title();
$driver->quit();
```

After 45 second I get error from the driver:

```
Could not create new session: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
 at (eval 89) line 510.
```

Seems like firefox launched by the driver does not see DISPLAY environment variable. I try to add it from the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
$ENV{DISPLAY}=":99";
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(browser_name=>'firefox');
$driver->get('http://www.google.com');
print $driver->get_title();
$driver->quit();
```

It does not help, the previous error remains. 
What do I do?

**EDIT2**

I tried the current setup with Python. All works.

```
# pip install selenium
```

And used the following test script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
f = open('ptn-sel.txt', 'w')
f.write(driver.title)
driver.close()
f.close()
```

I understand it's problem of Perl driver.... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is python using the standalone server or running firefox itself?

If perl is using the server and the server is spawning firefox then you need `$DISPLAY` set in the server processes environment not the script's environment. (By running `export DISPLAY=:99; java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.49.0.jar`or similar.)

If you don't want to use the standalone server at all then [Selenium::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver-0.2701/lib/Selenium/Firefox.pm) looks like it might be interesting.

Comment: I'll check Selenium::Firefox. But how do I set DISPLAY in the server?

Comment: You export it in the shell before you run the standalone server so that the standalone server gets it set in its environment.

Comment: Solved the problem. export DISPLAY=:99 && java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.49.0.jar